# Orchard CMS build script - not all modules are published

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm using Orchard 1.6 and have a question regarding the build batch file.

When run, some default modules (Lucene, Content Permissions, Messages) do not get published.  I cannot see any difference in file permissions between these modules and the modules that are included in the publish.

Dropping the DLL's in the dependencies folder works, but, I'd like to fix this issue with the build script.  No errors are reported by the build script.

If it makes a difference, I'm using TFS 2010 for version control.

Really appreciate any pointers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the orchard.proj file. That's what the build script is using.

Comment: Great stuff- these modules are excluded in the MsDeploy-Exclude-Modules section, have changed to suit my needs.
Can you advise why these are excluded in the script?

Comment: As far as I know, they are not excluded anymore in 1.7.